# リンク集や関連する質問を設定することはできますか？

Tags: サポート

（ヘルプで出てこなかったので質問させていただきます。）
リンク集や関連する質問はどのように決まっているのでしょうか？
また、自分で設定することは可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### リンク集

他の質問のURLを質問・回答・コメントに書くことで追加されます。見たところ、リンクを張られた側にも同様に追加されるようですね。

また、「重複」としてクローズした場合にも、重複候補へのリンクが追加されます。

参考 [What is the difference between the Linked and the related questions in the side tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247887/286934)

### 関連する質問

質問に含まれる単語やタグを基準に、似ていると思われる質問をピックアップします。

参考 [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/286934)

このリストは投稿時に生成されるほか、[メタSEの投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71506/286934)によると、

- その質問や回答が「編集」された
- 新しい回答が投稿された
- （30日以上前の質問のみ）質問の閲覧ごとに3割程度の確率

をきっかけに、[適当なタイミングで](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176001/286934#comment528050_176001)更新されるようです。

---

というわけで、

> 自分で設定することは可能なのでしょうか？

どちらのリストも直接編集することはできません。